# Convert Cell Array to Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array with mixed data types: `ID`, which is a string, and the rest is numeric. I used `cell2mat()` but it did not work. I also tried separating the `ID` From the cell and then converting but received an error that it's only one dimension.

A sample for the  data is :

```
ID            A       B     C       K         L
'A_P66027'  6.49    6.48    6.4     6.404   6.2508
'B_P77178'  5.92    6.47    6.68    6.404   6.661
'K_P212522' 8.49    8.54    9.36    8.901   9.35
'C_P934473' 5.81    5.91    5.79    5.792   5.823
'L_P9671'   11.52   11.63   12.28   11.956  11.481
```

How do I convert this cell array to a matrix?

`A` is my Cell so i tried :

```
B=cell2mat(A);  % it does not work.
Id=A(:,1);
C=cell2mat(Id);  % also does not work ?
```

Comment: Please give an example (code + data) of what you are trying.

Comment: @Daniel  i put a sample for the data

Comment: Could you please properly format your "data" and code is still appreciated. ;)

Comment: Does the cell array contain the headers? You said you tried separating the ID and converting, how did you do this and what is the *exact* error message?

Comment: The data  appear in this way :(

Answer (score 1):

Discard the first column:

```
foo = {'A_P66027'  6.49    6.48    6.4     6.404   6.2508; ...
'B_P77178'  5.92    6.47    6.68    6.404   6.661; ...
'K_P212522' 8.49    8.54    9.36    8.901   9.35; ...
'C_P934473' 5.81    5.91    5.79    5.792   5.823; ...
'L_P9671'   11.52   11.63   12.28   11.956  11.481 };

cell2mat( foo(:, 2:end) );
```

Edit: if the header is included (also discard first row):

```
foo2 = {
'ID',       'A',    'B',    'C',    'K',    'L'; ...
'A_P66027'  6.49    6.48    6.4     6.404   6.2508; ...
'B_P77178'  5.92    6.47    6.68    6.404   6.661; ...
'K_P212522' 8.49    8.54    9.36    8.901   9.35; ...
'C_P934473' 5.81    5.91    5.79    5.792   5.823; ...
'L_P9671'   11.52   11.63   12.28   11.956  11.481 };

cell2mat( foo2(2:end, 2:end) );
```

Comment: @Mathias  I discard the first one , but i need the first one as matrix , vector ?

Comment: @navin: sorry mixed up the terms for column and row. What do you mean? The text labels?

Comment: @navin: What do you mean by "array format"? Can you please again use your sample data to show what you mean?

Comment: @ Matthias :ID is cell is not matrix , when i separate it is like that ( {}Id ) , i need to convert it to a mat ?  i need the whole cell array convert to array ( mat)

Comment: @navin: What should your result look like. Sorry, but I don't get your last answer.

Comment: @ Matthias  :it  should look like a mat not a cell :(

Comment: @navin: ```['ID'; 'A '; 'B '; 'C '; 'K '; 'L ']``` - this is a 6x2 char matrix. ?

Comment: I just need the ID which the column one:       
A_P66027'
B_P77178'
K_P212522'
C_P934473'
L_P9671'  in  mat format ?

Comment: Character array? ```char( foo2(2:end, 1) ) ``` gives you the labels of the first column (without ```'ID'```)

Comment: @navin, what do you want as a final result. Please edit your post to show what you want *exactly*. You won't be able to mix char/string data and numeric data in a simple matrix.

Comment: @mathias :   cell2mat( foo(:, 2:end) );  produce error which is :array must be of same type . and 
cell2mat( foo2(2:end, 2:end) );
will omit the ID and its not useful for me :( . and char( foo2(2:end, 1) ) produce char , i can not work on it  i need the ID in its original format.:(

Comment: @navin: okay, my last try - please show your required results in your updated post above. What does ```foo(:, 2:end)``` show in your example?